# Creating a method in Python

Tags: python, methods

I am trying to create a method in python that can be called upon later, but when I run the code, it no longer works. (The code worked before I tried making it into a method) I am not trying to create a class or anything else too fancy, just trying to get a working method that can be called upon. There is no error that was displayed, the program just wouldn't run how it should.

I am fairly new to Python programming, I would be thankful for any help

```
def func():
x= int(input())
while (x>1):
    if x%2 == 0:
        x = x//2
        print(x)
    elif x%2 != 0:
        x= x*3+1
        print(x)
func()
```

Please be kind, let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: You could just make your own module and call it up when needed. Put it in site-packages with the others

Comment: @SuperStew put it in site-packages??

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect. But, assuming the indentation was correct, you haven't called the function so nothing actually runs

Comment: @SuperStew Not in site-packages. In Lib. site-packages may also work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating a method in object oriented programming with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447745/creating-a-method-in-object-oriented-programming-with-python)

Comment: Edited your post with the error which should have been included otherwise

Comment: @mad_ no, don't do that. You're making assumptions

Comment: @roganjosh the above code is syntactically incorrect and no error has been added in the post. What assumptions can I possibly make??

Comment: @mad_ only OP can and should clarify their post. Guesswork is unhelpful.

Comment: @SuperStew Deb is simply trying to create a function. She isn't asking about how to create or install a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong. Either use spaces or tabs but consistently.

```
def func():
  x= int(input())
  while (x>1):
    if x%2 == 0:
      x = x//2
      print(x)
    elif x%2 != 0:
      x= x*3+1
      print(x)

func()
```

Comment: I had been using tabs, you also added the function call which helped me a great deal, when the indentation was fixed and I added the call the code ran as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is just the formatting here, but did you indent correctly inside the method? 
it should be:

```
def func():
    x= int(input())
    while (x > 1):
        if x % 2 == 0:
            x = x // 2
            print(x)
        elif x % 2 != 0:
            x= x * 3 + 1
            print(x)
```

if this is not the case, tell us what error are you getting when trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

You need to slightly change indentation

```
def func():
    x= int(input())
    while (x>1):
        if x%2 == 0:
            x = x//2
            print(x)
        else:
            x= x*3+1
            print(x)
```

When I run in Jupyter Notebook

```
func()
2
1
```

Install Jupyter from
[jupyter](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/jupyter)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add indentation, and I prefer to use input out of function.

Then you can reuse your function logic.

Of course it depends on your scenario.

```
def func(x):
    while (x>1):
        if x%2 == 0:
            x = x//2
            print(x)
        elif x%2 != 0:
            x= x*3+1
            print(x)

x= int(input())
func(x)
```

Comment: Hi Bob, to help others understand your answer, consider including a short description of your code and how it solves the queston.